# Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file while runnig main.dart from vs code

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'E:\User\Documents\Practise\Practice\Practice\Flutter\flutter_application_1\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\3d075fs9hjp81ny0sgym4v09w).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 5s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  Exited (sigterm)

i was trying flutter in vs code for first time i clicked on new project opened main.dart and clicked on run for output and it gave me error  the os i am using is windows 10 emulator is running android 10